# Post slider with custom post type

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I'm trying to create a post slider, but I'm stuck at this point.

I have created a taxonomy named 'slideshow' and a custom post type 'slider'. In this custom post type 'slider' , I have  assigned a taxonomy 'slideshow'

[image]

This working fine, but no matter what I've tried for the query, I still cannot get the images which is assigned for homeslide taxonomy ONLY.

Is there a better way to create a post slider. Any sugggestions will be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
function wms_slider_init() {
    $labels = array(
        'name' => 'Slider',
        'singular_name' => 'Slider',
        'add_new' => 'Add Slider',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add New Slider',
        'edit_item' => 'Edit Slider',
        'new_item' => 'New Slider',
        'all_items' => 'All Sliders',
        'view_item' => 'View Slider',
        'search_items' => 'Search Sliders',
        'not_found' =>  'No Slider found',
        'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Slider found in Trash', 
        'parent_item_colon' => '',
        'menu_name' => 'Sliders'
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'description'   => 'Holds our Slider poste specific data',
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true, 
        'show_in_menu' => true, 
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'slider' ),
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'has_archive' => false, 
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'page-attributes')
    ); 
    register_post_type( 'slider', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wms_slider_init' );
add_action( 'init', 'wms_create_slider_taxonomies', 0 );

//create SlideShow Category for the post type "slider"
function wms_create_slider_taxonomies() {

    // Add new taxonomy, make it hierarchical (like categories)
    $labels = array(
        'name'                => _x( 'SlideShows', 'taxonomy general name' ),
        'singular_name'       => _x( 'SlideShow', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
        'search_items'        => __( 'Search Genres' ),
        'all_items'           => __( 'All SlideShows' ),
        'parent_item'         => __( 'Parent SlideShow' ),
        'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Parent SlideShow:' ),
        'edit_item'           => __( 'Edit SlideShow' ), 
        'update_item'         => __( 'Update SlideShow' ),
        'add_new_item'        => __( 'Add New SlideShow' ),
        'new_item_name'       => __( 'New SlideShow Name' ),
        'menu_name'           => __( 'SlideShow' )
    );    

    $args = array(
        'hierarchical'        => true,
        'labels'              => $labels,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_admin_column'   => true,
        'query_var'           => true,
        'rewrite'             => array( 'slug' => 'slideshow' )
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'slideshow', array( 'slider' ), $args );
}
?>
```

Comment: I have a free plugin called Nemus Slider and you can create a slider based on posts/post types easily. Maybe this is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough rep to comment, but what does your actual query look like?

**Edit**: I haven't been able to test it, but I think this will work

```
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'slider',
        'meta_key' => '_thumbnail_id', // only pull sliders with images
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'slideshow',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => 'homeslide',
                'operator' => 'IN'
            )
         )
    )
```

`$query = new WP_Query( $args);`

Then follow the normal loop

Comment: i erased it now but it was like    query_posts(array( 
        'post_type' => 'slideshow',
        'showposts' => -1,
    ) ); and in addition to that tax_query sth like that.

Comment: i tried it already but it founds nothing var_dump doesnt show up anything do you have any idea why ?

Comment: does it find anything if you just run a query setting the post_type only?

Answer (score 0):

To display your custom post type as a slider, you'd first need a custom `WP_Query` to index your post type, then some code to actually display it as a slider. Here is a quick barebones example using [Unslider](http://unslider.com/)

```
    <!-- Include Unslider JS -->
    <!-- YOU SHOULD INCLUDE WP JQUERY -->
    <script src="//unslider.com/unslider.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Set up the necessary JS for the slider -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
        $('.banner').unslider({
            // Add other arguments here
            speed: 500
        })
    });
    </script>


    <!-- Output the HTML for the slider -->
    <?php 
    // Do the custom WP_Query first
        $query = new WP_Query( 
            array (
                'post_type' => 'slider',
                'meta_key' => '_thumbnail_id', // only pull sliders with images
                'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'slideshow',
                        'field' => 'slug',
                        'terms' => 'homeslide',
                        'operator' => 'IN'
                    )
                ),
            )
        );

    // if we have posts, display them:
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) : ?> 

    <!-- Some basic CSS for the slider -->
    <!-- Remember to add your own CSS styling -->
    <style type="text/css">
    .banner { position: relative; overflow: auto; }
        .banner li { list-style: none; }
            .banner ul li { float: left; }  
    </style>

    <!-- Some basic HTML for the slider
         Each slide is simply an <li>
         within a surrounding <ul>
         inside an encasing div -->
    <div class="banner">
        <ul>

        <?php // While we have posts, output them as <li>'s
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
            <li style="background-image: url(<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) ); ?>);">
                    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                    <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>          
            </li>
        <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <?php else : ?>
        <!-- ENTER HTML IF THERE'S NO SLIDES HERE -->
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Remember that for this there are some things you should do:

- Make sure you've at least 2/3 posts for the slider
- Make sure your posts are in the `homeslide` taxonomy and have **featured images**
- Make sure your theme has the WordPress JQuery enqueued
- Modify (and probably move) the JS and CSS in the code above as required
- Add some fallback code after the `else` for when there's no slides
- If you decide to stick with [Unslider](http://unslider.com/), check out the full range options

*Note: I tested this code by using your code to register the custom post type and taxonomy and creating a few test slides (with featured images) within the taxonomy of `homeslide` so it should work no problem*

Comment: nope didnt work for me :( var_dump gives me null here is the query wp_posts.post_type = 'slider' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_author = 1 AND wp_posts.post_status = 'private') AND (wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id' )

Comment: Do you get any posts if you run `$query = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'slider')); var_dump($query);`?

Comment: yes Martin its okay with just post_type slider.when i checked the posts which are in slider type ,there is a column named post_type and its value is slider but no relationship with taxonomy slideshow or homeslide strings in phpmyadmin

Comment: Thats fine, taxonomies are saved in a separate table within the WP database and the `WP_Query` does the SQL `JOIN` on the two. Have you ensured that your posts are **both** in the category of `homeslide` and have **featured images** set? (In your screenshot in the original post, there is no featured image). I have tested this code with the same setup that from the code you posted and it works no problem

Comment: yes exaclty everything looks fine but it doesnt work , maybe we can communicate on skype better if you wish ?

Comment: Yes, as we can't move this into chat perhaps skype would be better